# How to import csv files into hbase table in a different schema

Tags: csv, hadoop, hbase, bulk-load

I've recently started working on hbase and know not much about it. I have multiple csv files (around 20000) and I want to import them into a HBase table in a way that each file would be a row in hbase, and the name of the file would be the rowkey. It means each row of the csv file is a cell in hbase, which I need to put them in a struct datatype(of 25 fields). Unfortunately, I have no clue for the problem. If anyone would be kind to give me some tip to start I appreciate it.

Here is a sample of the csv files:

```
time, a, b, c, d, ..., x
0.000,98.600,115.700,54.200,72.900,...,0.000
60.000,80.100,113.200,54.500,72.100,...,0.000
120.000,80.000,114.200,55.200,72.900,...,0.000
180.000,80.000,118.400,56.800,75.500,...,0.000
240.000,80.000,123.100,59.600,79.200,...,0.000
300.000,80.000,130.100,61.600,82.500,...,0.000
```

Thanks,

Comment: I would suggest using Hive for CSV files, not Hbase. From Hive, you're more than welcome to load an Hbase table

Comment: I'd never thought that before, thanks, I'll look into that. But I need to know if there is a way to load data into HBase first.

Comment: Sure, there are ways. Read lines of a CSV file, put them into a column family with a `HTable.put` command (or use a Spark HBase connector). It's not clear what your HBase table structure currently looks like, though.

Comment: I want to have one column-family (time), and the name of the file would be the row-key, then for each row-key and column I want to have all the 24 fields as a struct. I don't know if it's clear now. Would you please give me some details, where should I start from? If there is any tutorial, or example that can be a help please send me the link.

Comment: Asking for links and tutorials is considered off topic for Stackoverflow. Plus, I don't actually know Hbase

Answer (score 0):

Importtsv is a utility that will load data in TSV or CSV format into HBase.

Importtsv has two distinct usages:

1. Loading data from TSV or CSV format in HDFS into HBase via Puts.
2. Preparing StoreFiles to be loaded via the completebulkload.

Load Data from TSV or CSV format in HDFS to Hbase
Below is the example that allows you to load data from hdfs file to HBase table. You must copy the local file to the hdfs folder then you can load that to HBase table.

$ hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator=',' -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY, personal_data:name, personal_data:city, personal_data:age personal /test
The above command will generate the MapReduce job to load data from CSV file to HBase table.